# How do I read the Wires from a 180 DIN with an Arduino's analog ports to read Nintendo Controller?

Tags: arduino, serial, ps2

I have a USB Super Nintendo controller. I'm attempting to read the buttons with an Arduino Uno. I found a suggestion to utilize a USB too Ps/2 adapter. I've done that then I found a Serial ps/2 to 180 DIN connector. I split off the big end and found 4 wires. (red, black, orange, and brown)

I am unsure of how to wire it to the Arduinos analog input. My best guess is to wire the black to ground, the red t 5v with a 220 ohm resistor, and then orange and brown each to seperate analog input ports. Is this correct?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've never dealt with one of those controllers, but assuming the controller supports the PS/2 protocol so will work with one of those passive adapters then PS/2 is a digital interface with a clock and data line.

Comment: There are no analog signals in the USB connector coming from the game controller. While there are some USB HIDs (human interface devices) such as keyboards and mice that can also switch to PS/2 protocol (with a mechanical adapter for the connector) for backward compatibility, I doubt this is true of the game controller. But the point is, there still wouldn't be any analog signals to read; both USB and PS/2 are digital protocols.

Comment: What if I cut the USB cord and accessed the wires, could I read the signals then? (perhaps with the arduino digital input?)

Comment: No. The best you could do would be to open up the game controller, remove or disable the existing electronics inside and connect wires between each of the actual switch contacts and the digital inputs of your Arduino.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I found a suggestion to utilize a USB too Ps/2 adapter.

They will only work for *some* mice and keyboards, because they are completely passive - that means the PC/2 protocol must be supported in the USB device, too.

It is highly unlikely that your USB controller supports the PS/2 protocol, so this solution will not work.

You would need a device with USB *Host* capability to connect your controller to, like an USB host shield that supports HID device class.

Comment: "for some" Rule of thumb is: If the device came with the adapter then it supports both USB and PS/2, if the device didn't come with an adaptor, it will only support USB.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a real Super Nintendo controller. Then use the Arduino to read that. The real super Nintendo controller uses a simple 16 bit shift register protocol. Pull the latch low, pulse the clock, read the data pin. Simple as pi.

Your USB controller is either a real controller hacked with a microcontroller converting the shift register to usb hid, a hacked controller that removed the original ic and wired its own microcontroller in, or a custom designed board. Either way, it requires a usb host to read it's USB HID output.